# Creating a Spring MVC project using Intellij 2020

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

i'm trying to create a spring MVC project using intellij Ultimate 2020 but i don't have it available in my menu :

[image]

Is there a way to get the Spring option ? i already checked that the Spring plugins are all enabled .
[image]

Comment: Spring Initializr initializes your Spring Boot proyect like a charm.

Comment: Can't reproduce in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.2, [see the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/W5st52L.png). To investigate further please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Initializr can generate a Spring Boot project structure for you. It will give you a basic project structure and either a Maven or a Gradle build specification to build your code with.
You can use Spring Initializer to generate a spring project. It will provide you with all the dependencies required for SpringMVC project

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://start.spring.io/.
Just specify the dependencies.
Download the generated project.
Open the project with IntelliJ.
Resolve the dependencies by specifying the unmet ones in pom.xml if found any.

Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know are u new in spring, but if u are, here some advice to start in idea.

First of all, visit https://start.spring.io/

First 5 steps of instruction matches with numbers on this picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6NW1.png

1. Choose dependencies u need, for example start with **spring web(mvc)**
2. Choose your language, u need **java**
3. Choose which dependency manager u will use, for example **maven**
4. Choose spring boot version, for example **2.3.3**
5. Give a proper name to your future project, it's not necessary
6. Press **GENERATE**
7. Unzip downloaded file
8. IntelliJ Idea -> Open or Import - > select unziped folder